# Connection with Azure File Share using MSI not working

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to connect to Azure File Share but it is throwing Authentication Error.

```
AzureServiceTokenProvider tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string accessToken = await tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/", "");

log.LogInformation(accessToken);
TokenCredential tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(accessToken);
StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);

Uri fileAddress = new Uri("File URI");
CloudFile sourceFile = new CloudFile(fileAddress, storageCredentials);
log.LogInformation(await sourceFile.DownloadTextAsync());
```

> Error: Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly
>   including the signature.

The same approach works for Azure Blob Storage.

I have assigned **Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor** role to Managed Identity of my Azure Function.

Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The same approach works for Azure Blob Storage.

**Azure Storage not support using AAD to authorize File storage.**

Azure Storage supports using Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) to authorize requests to [**Blob and Queue storage**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad).

Azure Files supports authorization with Azure AD over SMB for domain-joined VMs only. To learn about using Azure AD over SMB for Azure Files, see [Overview of Azure Active Directory authorization over SMB for Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-overview).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have connected Azure File Share with Connection String.